# How to get audio streams for my android radio app?

Tags: android, internet-radio

If I take streams(for my android app) from existing radio streaming websites, would it cause any copyright problems or anything? If yes, then can anyone suggest sites with whom such a problem will not occur?
edit:
I don't wan't individual stations but a website that streams a bunch of non-affiliated stations like radioreference.com

Answer (score 1):

We use Shoutcast, They have over 50,000 stations available and a simple API.

Comment: How did you get them to give you their API? Offered to share revenue or something?

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the website individually to determine whether there's a license required.

A quick google search of "license free radio stations" produced this website which lists a number of roylaty-free stations:
`http://tunein.com/radio/Royalty-Free-Music-Radio-s112624/`

However, it looks like even the license-free stations have copyright notices so you would need to contact the stations individually to secure permissions.

Another course of action is to get radio stations to sign up with you and agree for their content to be broadcast through your app as a way of increasing their outreach.

Good luck!

Comment: quick question: will I run into any legal problems with royalty free stations if i use them without their permission?

Comment: I edited my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any opinions about my question's edit above?